# heatmap with highlighting and segmented colormap

Tags: javascript, google-maps, heatmap, color-scheme

I became acquainted with such wonderful article -[How NOT to Lie with Visualization](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~tmm/courses/533/readings/pravda/truevis.htm)
And of couse tried to use the recommendations.
Two types of heatmap colormap from the article seem to be very interesting: highlighting and segmented colormaps: [types of colormap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgQ8i.jpg) (sry, not enough reputation to post images)

All types of JS heatmap libs for google maps, that I know can build only gradient between some colors, which allows to build default (rainbow) and isomorphic colormaps.
so my question is: 
Is there any JS lib for google maps, that can produce such types of heatmap as segmented and highlighting ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution:

1. highlighting colormap:
   I've made a range slider, where the range means the highlighted space:
   by change the slider values, the new gradient is calculated as

```js
    var new_gradient =[]; 
    new_gradient[0] = 'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)'; 
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {   
      if ( (i >= v1) && (i <= v2)) 
        { new_gradient.push('#ffff00'); }   
      else 
        { new_gradient.push('#00008b'); }         
    };
```

bright yellow is a highlighted space, blue - is not.

---

2. Segmented colormap:
   in Google Maps JavaScript API v3 the colors , which you push into the gradient array are evenly distributed over the scale (if we'd draw the legend, it would be easier to see). If you push same color - there would be no gradient between them. So if you push 100 colors, instead of 10, where 1-80 would be #00008b and 81-100 - #ffff00. the gradient would be built between 80 and 81 colors, that would be almost imperceptible